# Which Rendering Engine or Game Engine for Simulation with CUDA and F# Back-end

Tags: cuda, f#, gpu, game-engine, simulation

I'm putting together a simulation environment catered towards multi-agent/swarm robotic simulation.  The parts I'll be doing from scratch are the math library, physics engine, and AI engine.  These will be implemented in F#/CUDA.  I'm looking for advice on how to best implement everything else - i.e. all of the other parts of a game engine.  After a bit of research in the beginning, it seemed like OGRE would be my best bet but I'm still unsure.  Basically, I want to concentrate on the physics/ai stuff and have some game engine do everything else for me - rendering, scene graphs, etc.

Something I'm confused about is how my F#/CUDA back-end will interact with the rendering engine/game engine.  It seems like the popular engines are set up so you could replace parts of the architecture with your own implementations fairly easily...  Which one would be best for me to use?

Since I'm using CUDA and will be rendering results from the gpu, how will this affect implementation of a rendering engine like OGRE? I know I can't be stuck just having to use straight OpenGL...

Currently, I'm looking at Ogre, Panda3D, jMonkey, and Gazebo.  On the surface, Gazebo seems like it could be exactly what I'm looking for.

I am also considering Python and Lua, though I'm leaning towards the latter.

I'd like for this "simulation environment" to be able to easily converted to (or just used as) a real game engine.  I know all of the elements would pretty much be there already, I'm just stating that in case it helps with giving me advice.

Also, I would *really* like for this thing to be able to run on the CUDA-capable Tegra 4s that are supposed to come out this quarter (last I checked).  This may or may not be something that can accurately be determined at this point, but you guys will know better than me... i.e. if I want the possibility of future tegra/android use, I should do everything in jMonkey?  Would it matter?

...Overall I'm most interested in advice on what architecture configuration would work well with a F#/CUDA physics & ai engine

Comment: I voted to close. This is an excellent question but it is too open ended for SO. Please see the [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) in the FAQ.

Comment: I was trying to avoid asking "Which is the best...?"  It was hard to word my question.. As is, It does seem open ended, but I didn't intend for it to be.  It's worded toward "Discuss what could work" but I'm really after "Someone confirm something that WILL work."  I'm trying to avoid shooting myself in the foot as I venture into new territory with this project :)

Comment: @acbrewbaker You're almost certainly pioneering.